# My phone sees the NIR from a TV remote. Why does it not see the NIR in rainbows?

Tags: dispersion, infrared-radiation, camera, imaging

My Pixel phone's camera shows the IR light from the LED of a TV remote as a magenta/lavender color. That wavelength is likely around 940 nm.

Now, when I take a picture of a rainbow in the sky, it does not show a magenta band some distance away from the edge of the red band (~700 nm). Similarly, if I make my own rainbow with a glass prism and the light of the Sun, the phone does not display any magenta past the edge of the red band. Why is that?

As part of my inquiry in the case of the prism experiment, I have checked that I can detect the IR past the red band using thermochromic film. Also, standard glass should be transparent to IR in the 700-1000 nm range.

Thanks for your input, it would be greatly appreciated :)

[Edited to reframe the question in the larger context of rainbows]

Comment: Is it possible to add the pictures you took with the Pixel phone camera? When you say standard glass, is this prism is not especially manufactured for optics? There are several types of glasses, so I am asking in case it is some specific type of glass which may have special absorption lines.

Comment: In part as a process of elimination set up your prism and place a thermometer with a blackened bulb in the region where you expect the ir to be.  Is there any increase in the temperature reading on the thermometer?  [An illustration of a possible procedure?](https://edu.rsc.org/download?ac=15129)

Comment: A possible cause is that the visible light is saturating the phone sensor so have you tried to mask off the visible light and the uv by using a slit before the camera sensor?

Comment: The IR LED is extremely bright. Your other IR sources may be too faint.

Answer (score 2):

My interpretation is that, while your camera has some sensitivity for NIR, it's much lower than that for visible light. That's a design goal for cameras, as we want them to reproduce the visible spectrum the way that the human eye sees it. Everything else is unwanted and typically blocked by filters (which does not work prefectly, as you see).

When looking into the IR LED of a remote control, it is very bright. Typically, you'll do such shots inside where it's always much darker than e.g. a bright sunlit day outside. Repeat the test under full-sun conditions, and I bet the LED will appear much fainter.

Rainbows typically do not have a high contrast against the sky/clouds background, so while in theory there should be the NIR band present, it will be so dim as to be indistinguishable from the background, after the camera's IR filter.

Sunlight through a prism should show a fair amount of NIR, but again the camera will adapt its exposure setting to the dominant (after the IR filter) visible part of the spectrum, and the NIR will easily drop below the noise level.

Maybe you can somehow block the visible part (e.g. by projecting the spectrum onto a sheet of paper, and letting the visible part pass beyond its edge - but you still need to block out any ambient light that has not passed the prism, so the sheet looks completely black to your eye), and then you should see something.